# Python Pandas Seaborn FacetGrid: use dataframe series' names to set up columns

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, facet-grid

I am using pandas dataframes to hold some volume calculation results,  and trying to configure a seaborn FacetGrid setup to visualize results of 4 different types of volume calculations for a reservoir zone.

I believe I can handle the dataframe part, my problems is with the visualization part:
Each different type of volume calculations is loaded in the dataframe as a series. The series name corresponds to the type of volume calculation. I want to create a number of plots then, aligned so that each column of plot corresponds to one series in my dataframe.

Theory (documentation) says this should do it (example from tutorial at https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matpltlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g=sns.FacetGrid(tips, col = "time")
```

I cannot find the referenced dataset "tips" for download, but I think that is a minor problem. From the code snippet above and after some testing on my own data, I infer that "time" in that dataset refers to the name of **one series** in the dataframe and that different times would then be different categories or other types of values in that series.

This is not how my dataset is ordered. I have the different types of volume calculations that I would see as individual plots (in columns) represented as series in my dataframe. How do I provide the series name as input to seaborn FacetGrid col= argument?

```
g = seaborn.FacetGrid(data=volumes_table, col=?????)
```

I cannot figure out how I can get col=dataframe.series and I cannot find any documented example of that.

here's a setup with some exciting dummy names and dummy values

```
import os
import pandas
import numpy
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#provide some input data, using a small dictionary
volumes_categories = {'zone_numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'zone_names': ['corona', 'hiv', 'h5n1', 'measles'],
 'grv': [30, 90, 80, 100],
 'nv': [20, 60, 20, 50],
 'pv': [5, 12, 4, 25],
 'hcpv': [4, 6, 1, 20]}

# create the  dataframe
volumes_table = pandas.DataFrame(volumes_categories)

# set up for plotting
seaborn.set(style='ticks')
g= seaborn.FacetGrid(data=volumes_table, col='zone_names')
```

The above setup generates columns ok, but I cannot get the  colums to represent series in my dataframe (the columns when visualizing the dataframe as a table....)

What do I need to do?

Comment: IIUC, try restructuring your data to long-form first - check out [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). Something like `volumes_table.melt(id_vars=['zone_numbers', 'zone_names'])` for example, then `g= seaborn.FacetGrid(data=volumes_table, col='variable')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once we imported all requirements:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
```

The FacetGrid essentially just provides a canvas to draw on. You can then use the map function to "project" plotting functions onto the canvas:

```py
# Blueprint
g = sns.FacetGrid(dataframe, col="dataframe.column", row="dataframe.column")
g = g.map(plotting.function, "dataframe.column")

# Example with the tips dataset
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", row="smoker")
g = g.map(plt.hist, "total_bill")
plt.show()
```

In your case as mentioned above I would also melt the columns first to get a tidy data format and then plot as usual. Changing what to plot however necessary:

```py
volumes_table = volumes_table.melt(id_vars=['zone_numbers', 'zone_names'])
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=volumes_table, col='variable')
g = g.map(plt.scatter, 'zone_numbers', 'value')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for pointing up spelling mistakes, I updated the top post

Comment: not quite there yet, posted just before leaving work so didn't get time to get it working yet.

Answer (score 1):

The main part of the solution is described in BBQuercus's answer: reshaping the nice, human-readable wide-format dataframe/table into a long-format table which is simpler to digest for seaborn, using seaborn.melt()

I implemented this by creating a copy of the original dataframe and melting the copy:

```
# first copy dataframe
vol_table2 = volumes_table.copy()

#melt it into long format
vol_table2 = pandas.melt(vol_table2, id_vars = ['zone_numbers','zone_names'], value_vars=['grv','nv','pv','hcpv'], var_name = "volume_type", value_name = "volume")
```

In the end I also decided to scrap the explicit FacetGrid and map setup and use seaborn.catplot (with FacetGrid functionality included).

Thanks for assistance 
(PS:  it must be a good idea for seaborn to accept series names for Facetgrid setup)